# How to display some widgets slowly one by one in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want to display some text and containers one by one slowly as shown in the below gif. I tried in list view also but could not achieve it. If anyone has any ideas could you suggest me?.
[image: Refrence from reflecty app]

Comment: Use a package named flutter_staggered_animations

Comment: If you wish to undertand how to create this effects on oyur own take a look at the [animation section](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations) of the docs. And for a concrete example [this cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/effects/staggered-menu-animation) about staggered animations

Answer (score 0):

For this particular example in the video, you can use the [flutter_staggered_animations](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_animations) package.